# Can any other programs affect receiving WhatsApp messages when in use?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, internet, network-signal

Curious as to why one gray tick happens when sending a WhatsApp message, as well as why calls are not being received.

Is it possible that another program conflicts with WhatsApp and the ability to receive text messages or telephone calls when using any other program? Or is it strictly an issue with data?

I ask because sometimes my messages and calls are not received over WhatsApp. My end will only register one grey tick, and I am told the phone never rang on their end sometimes when I call.

Just wondering if any other programs like Skype or Google Meet or like programs interfere with WhatsApp and cause the messages to be held in transit, leaving one gray tick, or calls not to go through.

Answer (score 1):

One app can't influence another in this fashion. I have seen this on my phone on these conditions

1. Airplane mode is on
2. Mobile data is off
3. The phone has dicey or no connection to the mobile network.